# Using current target inside apply block

Tags: puppet, puppet-bolt

I'd like to know if it possible to retrieve the current target inside an *apply* block in Bolt.

For example, I'd like to bootstrap puppet on remote machine using the following plan:

```
# @summary This plan installs Puppet and configure it to use emypuppet-master.local as Puppet master
# @param targets The targets to run on.
plan puppet_bootstrapping::install_and_configure (
  TargetSpec $targets,
) {
  out::message("Installing Puppet")

  apply_prep($targets)

  apply($targets, '_description' => 'Configuring Puppet') {
    class {'::puppet_agent':
      manage_repo => false,
      config => [
        {section => main, setting => runinterval, value => '30m'},
        {section => main, setting => environment, ensure => absent},
        {section => main, setting => servername, value => 'mypuppet-master.local'},
        {section => main, setting => certname, value => ????????}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How do I get the name of the target for the *certname* value ? Is there a special value as if we were running it in a loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep! You can access facts inside an apply block just like Puppet code, including trusted facts:

```
# @summary This plan installs Puppet and configure it to use mypuppet-master.local as Puppet master
# @param targets The targets to run on.
plan puppet_bootstrapping::install_and_configure (
  TargetSpec $targets,
) {
  out::message("Installing Puppet")

  apply_prep($targets)

  apply($targets, '_description' => 'Configuring Puppet') {
    class {'::puppet_agent':
      manage_repo => false,
      config => [
        {section => main, setting => runinterval, value => '30m'},
        {section => main, setting => environment, ensure => absent},
        {section => main, setting => servername, value => 'mypuppet-master.local'},
        {section => main, setting => certname, value => $trusted['certname']}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```